# uiwebview problem loading page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

My webpage will not load it shows nothing I have 3 viewcontrollers in firstviewcontroller  you click the button which loads the next page thirdviewcontroller  up to this point all is good but the webpage doesnt load

code from firstviewcontroller

```
-(IBAction)moveToViewSiteView:(id)sender{

    self.third = [[[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.third animated:YES];
}
```

code in thirdviewcontroller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSString *urlAddress=@"http://www.apple.com/";
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj= [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.cscsPage loadRequest:requestObj];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

the uiwebview i have called webview in the document window in ib if i drag from files owner to the webview then when i run it the app crashes.

hope all is clear

thanks

Comment: Your class name & XIB name is different? In this line self.third = [[[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];

Comment: put a break point in viewDidLoad method and check it will come or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `[super viewDidLoad];` to the top of viewDidLoad method. You should invoke the super class implementation of it first.